# Pyramid authorization for stored items

Tags: python, authorization, policy, pyramid

I'm trying to create an authorization policy that takes "item" ownership into account. For example some user X "owns" items A, B, C. Those are accessed via URLs like `/item/{item}/some_options`.

How can I get the information about `{item}` to the authorization policy object (permits() call)? Is putting additional information into context a good idea (I'm doing routes-based routing only). How would I do that?

Answer (score 52, accepted):

You can do this using the `ACLAuthorizationPolicy` combined with URL Dispatch by using a custom resource tree designed for this purpose.

For example, you have permissions for `Foo` objects, and permissions for `Bar` objects. These ACLs can be found by traversing the resource tree using the urls:

```
/foos/{obj}
/bars/{obj}
```

Your resource tree then becomes a hierarchy of permissions, where at any point in the tree you can place an `__acl__` on the resource object:

```
root                       (Root)
|- foos                    (FooContainer)
|  `- {obj}                (Foo)
`- bars                    (BarContainer)
   `- {obj}                (Bar)
```

You can represent this hierarchy in a resource tree:

```py
class Root(dict):
    # this is the root factory, you can set an __acl__ here for all resources
    __acl__ = [
        (Allow, 'admin', ALL_PERMISSIONS),
    ]
    def __init__(self, request):
        self.request = request
        self['foos'] = FooContainer(self, 'foos')
        self['bars'] = BarContainer(self, 'bars')

class FooContainer(object):
    # set ACL here for *all* objects of type Foo
    __acl__ = [
    ]

    def __init__(self, parent, name):
        self.__parent__ = parent
        self.__name__ = name

    def __getitem__(self, key):
        # get a database connection
        s = DBSession()
        obj = s.query(Foo).filter_by(id=key).scalar()
        if obj is None:
            raise KeyError
        obj.__parent__ = self
        obj.__name__ = key
        return obj

class Foo(object):
    # this __acl__ is computed dynamically based on the specific object
    @property
    def __acl__(self):
        acls = [(Allow, 'u:%d' % o.id, 'view') for o in self.owners]
        return acls

    owners = relation('FooOwner')

class Bar(object):
    # allow any authenticated user to view Bar objects
    __acl__ = [
        (Allow, Authenticated, 'view')
    ]
```

With a setup like this, you can then map route patterns to your resource tree:

```py
config = Configurator()
config.add_route('item_options', '/item/{item}/some_options',
                 # tell pyramid where in the resource tree to go for this url
                 traverse='/foos/{item}')
```

You will also need to map your route to a specific view:

```py
config.add_view(route_name='item_options', view='.views.options_view',
                permission='view', renderer='item_options.mako')
```

Great, now we can define our view and use the loaded context object, knowing that if the view is executed, the user has the appropriate permissions!

```py
def options_view(request):
    foo = request.context
    return {
        'foo': foo,
    }
```

Using this setup, you are using the default `ACLAuthorizationPolicy`, and you are providing row-level permissions for your objects with URL Dispatch. Note also, that because the objects set the `__parent__` property on the children, the policy will bubble up the lineage, inheriting permissions from the parents. This can be avoided by simply putting a `DENY_ALL` ACE in your ACL, or by writing a custom policy that does not use the context's lineage.

*** Update ***
I've turned this post into an actual demo on Github. Hopefully it helps someone.
https://github.com/mmerickel/pyramid_auth_demo

*** Update ***
I've written a full tutorial around pyramid's authentication and authorization system here: http://michael.merickel.org/projects/pyramid_auth_demo/

Comment: Suggestion for making your very helpful tutorial even more so: it would be good to discuss your use of Container here, as I was unsure of how to structure the resource tree when using a database connection.  I found this answer after seeing the tutorial, and it helped a lot.