# pyramid authorization of "top level" /{user} resource

Tags: python, authorization, pyramid

Similar to: [Dynamic user based authorization in Pyramid](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6585370/dynamic-user-based-authorization-in-pyramid)

Using URL dispatch, I want to dynamically assign a `permission` to a user where the `resource` is his/her *profile* page e.g. */aclark4life*:

- Anonymous visitors can access any user profile to see his/her activity.
- Authenticated users can access additional content on their *profile* page.

I can easily assign a "manage" `permission` to all authenticated users, but how do I ensure authenticated users can only view private content on their profile?

E.g. The end result should be only *aclark4life* can view "Connect to PyPI":

[image]

But anonymous viewers cannot:

[image]

Comment: I've wondered the same... I've got permissions set and managed for entire views in my pyramid apps, but usually end up hard coding conditions to optionally hide or display content within the view template based on whatever access the logged in user has.

Comment: I know of a way, but are you using traversal with url dispatch?

Comment: No traversal (unless you count the traversal that happens by default). And I've come up with something that works with help from Michael Merickel. Will post an answer soon.

Comment: @aclark Any update on what up ended up working for you?

Comment: @PeterTirrell The working code is here: https://github.com/pythonpackages/pythonpackages, haven't had a chance to answer the question yet though, sorry!